# Append Xml Attributes in a SQL server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

i'm new in handling xml inside sql server and i have a question that i have not found a example or a answer, so it will be very useful if you guys could help me.

I have various xml iside a table "T1" under a xml column type "xmlCol", This is the xml structure:

```
Row 1
<icfd:Ips totalIR="0" totalIT="7223.9">
  <icfd:Tras>
    <icfd:Tra impt="AIV" ts="16" imp="517.1"/>
    <icfd:Tra impt="SRI" ts="8" imp="18.3"/>
  </icfd:Tras>
</icfd:Ips>

Row 2
<icfd:Ips totalIR="10" totalIT="123.9">
  <icfd:Tras>
    <icfd:Tra impt="AIV" ts="34" imp="345.1"/>
  </icfd:Tras>
</icfd:Ips>
```

I'm trying to obtain a result like this:

```
Tra                     totalIR    totalIT
-------------------------------------------
AIV(517.1),SRI(18.3)    0          7223.9
AIV(345.1)              10         123.9
```

How could be a correct way to make this query?

i have this but i'm getting nowhere:

```
------------------ SQL server query -----------------------

WITH 
    XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.stwaree/icfd/3' AS icfd)
SELECT 
    B.value('@impt', 'varchar(max)') + '(' +
    B.value('@imp', 'varchar(max)') + ')' AS Tra
FROM
    [T1] CROSS APPLY [xmlCol].nodes('//icfd:Tra') AS A(B)

----------------------- Result ----------------------------

Tra        
----------
AIV(517.1)
SRI(18.3)
AIV(345.1)
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
with xmlnamespaces('http://www.stwaree/icfd/3' as icfd)
select T.XMLCol.query('for $i in /icfd:Ips/icfd:Tras/icfd:Tra 
                       return element X{concat(",", data($i/@impt), "(", data($i/@imp), ")")}'
                     ).value('substring(., 2)', 'nvarchar(max)') as Tra,
       T.XMLCol.value('/icfd:Ips[1]/@totalIR', 'varchar(10)') as totalIR,
       T.XMLCol.value('/icfd:Ips[1]/@totalIT', 'varchar(10)') as totalIT
from T;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/12c38/2)